# Is there a different deadline for Moshiach to come with mercy than to come with more harshness?

Tags: talmud-gemara, messiah, messianic-redemption

Chazal bring down that human history follows the seven days of creation, with each day representing 1,000 years, and the seventh day being a day of rest. Therefore, it follows that Moshiach must come no later than the year 6,000 of history in order for the last thousand years of the seven thousand to be the day of rest and Messianic Kingdom. However, is there a teaching that for Moshiach to come with mercy, because we got our act together, the deadline might be a couple hundred years earlier, approximately, than if we don't get our act together, and Moshiach comes from Divine providence to, in layman's terms, bail us out at the last minute?

*Is there an earlier deadline for Moshiach to come with mercy than to come with more judgement/harshness/sufferings, and if so, what is the date of that earlier deadline? (If my english terminology is not clear, see comment below for clarification)*

Todah rabah!

Comment: Terminology clarification: I think the terms mercy and judgement here can be confusing, because one might say that if we don't merit the Redemption ourselves, then it is an even bigger mercy for Hashem to still redeem us at all, even with judgement and harshness, than if Moshiach comes "with mercy" because we merit it, but, I don't know better terms to use so those are the ones I used. With that clarification, I hope is comprehensible to everybody, whether they are familiar with english terminology, Hebrew, or both.

Comment: If we got our act together, why should the deadline (for Moshiach to come with mercy) only be a couple hundred years earlier, approximately? Why not [on that day](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Taanit.1.1.18?ven=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_translation_and_commentary_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=bi&lang2=en) (if we would but hearken to His voice)?

Comment: The point is if we merit it with mercy, there is no deadline.

Comment: Your reference to the cycle of 6000 years corresponding to the 6 days of Creation and the seventh millennium relating to Shabbat are correct. But your assessment of how this relates to the coming of Moshiach and the final redemption is incorrect. The actual commencement of Shabbat in terms of G-d’s commandments isn’t at 3 medium stars. It is much earlier during the 6th day (Friday). We are at a different point in the cycle of redemption now.

Comment: @TamirEvan I meant deadline as in last positive chance to do it with merit, but if the merit comes before the deadline, then yes, it would happen on that day. 

N.T., my understanding was that there is a deadline either way at the end of the 6th day, because the final 1000 years is reserved for the Messianic era and it must start on time. So if we don't merit it with mercy before the deadline, then it still comes, but with judgement. I read this in I think Talmud Sanhedrin.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Well stated Yaacov, and this is one of things I was contemplating when asking the question. The footsteps to Moshiach start before the actual 1,000 year Messianic Kingdom. And on the Jewish calendar, days start with night. So we are already in friday, the 6th day as it were, but is the deadline for the Redemption to come with both mercy or judgement both the start of saturday, the 7th day, or both at a certain time on friday afternoon, or is one deadline earlier than another. Is the mercy deadline friday afternoon, but judgement deadline start of saturday? Or..? etc.

Comment: @TamirEvan OK I see what y mean now. That source brings up another scenario where Redemption happens at one time for the righteous, and another time for the wicked, altho it's confusing bc many sources say the wicked wont be redeemed period. That is an added layer of complexity to clear up I hadnt thought of in my question, but the first layer is, for the righteous specifically, say they don't harken to His voice until year 5950. Are they locked in until 6000 to be redeemed with harshness? Is 5950 too late for mercy? Or do they get redeemed the moment they harken so long as it's before 6000?

Comment: @TamirEvan In other words, what is the last possible moment to be be redeemed with mercy?

If someone harkens to His voice in 5999, can they be redeemed with mercy? Or is it a situation where, let's say, "you have until year 6,000 to be redeemed with harshness, if you are righteous enough to merit Redemption but not righteous enough to merit it with mercy. But you only have until year 5,900, or 5,800, to be redeemed with mercy. After that, you have to wait until year 6,000 no matter what, and it will still come with harshness." 

And what about for all Am Israel not just a single tzadik?

Comment: The correct understanding of the redemption & the coming of Moshiach is that it is all only in a way of mercy. (Think like the staff of Moshe and like the ashes of the red heifer, changing status. Even those prophetic statements that sound terrible & frightening will be expressed as mercy. According to traditional teaching, we are far beyond the period called “the heels or footsteps of Moshiach”. We are well into the actual days of Moshiach and more specifically the period referenced in Zechariah 13:2. For details, see Sefer Chesed l’Avraham by Rabbi Avraham Azulai, section Sod HaMikvah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks Yaacov. How can I reconcile this with Talmud Sanhedrin, maybe pages between 80 and 110 somewhere in there, that it can come with mercy or with harshness? I acknowledged in my comment at top this confusion of terms exists, but Im asking will our actions determine the extent of mercy, and is there a different deadline for Redemption in the most merciful way than a deadline for Redemption in a less-merciful-but-still-merciful way?

Comment: Your specific question is addressed in a Chassidic discourse from the 2nd Lubavitcher Rebbe discussing the phrase “in its time, I will hasten it”. What is presented in Sanhedrin is the layout for the entire parameter, meaning that the system is compromised of all 3 paths, kindness, severity and mercy. But mercy doesn’t mean the elimination or defeat of severity. Rather, it is the conversion of its state of being, like the staff of Moshe was converted from one state of being to another. This is also alluded to in the numerical equivalence of Moshiach and Nachash.